# TypeError: comparison did not return an int

Tags: python, comparison

I'm implementing something in python, specifically a **cmp** method for a class, here it is:

```
def __cmp__(self, other):
    if self.time < other.get_time():
        return -1
    if self.time > other.get_time():
        return 1
if self.type == A and other.get_type() == D:
        return -1
if self.type == D and other.get_type() == A:
    return 1
if self.person < other.get_person():
    return -1
if self.person > other.get_person():
    return 1
return 0
```

and I get this error when running the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "wp-proj03.py", line 292, in <module>
    main()
File "wp-proj03.py", line 180, in main
    events.put(e)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 136, in put
    self._put(item)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 225, in _put
    heappush(self.queue, item)
TypeError: comparison did not return an int
```

as you can see, I am using a queue, specifically a priority-queue (from the built-in Queue.py module). When i try to put an instance of my class into the queue, it throws this error.

Can someone tell me what is the problem with my comparison method? or could it be a problem somewhere else?

thx

Comment: You need to fix your indentation.

Comment: This looks like it could be an indentation problem, though normally, if `return` appeared outside a function, the code wouldn't even compile. Still, it'd be good to recheck your indentation. In particular, watch out for mixed tabs and spaces. Running Python with the `-tt` flag and turning on "show whitespace" in your editor can help.

Comment: You can simplify your code: `def __cmp__(self, other): return cmp(self.time, other.time) or cmp(self.type, other.type) or cmp(self.person, other.person)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably, due to the indentation problem mentioned by other commenters, your **cmp** function does not actually include the final return statement, and so in the case `self.time == other.get_time()`, `None` is returned (a default return value for a function exiting without an explicit `return`) instead of an integer that is expected as the result of `__cmp__`.

Comment: Hi again everyone. I don't have an indentation problem. The indentation was ruined when I copied the code here, and I didn't notice that. So ignore the indentation. thx.